# iOS Google map SDK price / cost

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am going to build an enterprise iOS app with map features. Considering using google maps sdk. However, I found that there are some limitation on the google maps api. If the traffic is high, google will charge some fee. But i dont know is it apply on the iOS API or not. 
Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq

Did someone tried to use google map sdk for iOS with a large user traffic? Is it free or charged?
Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usage limits don't apply to the mobile APIs, see here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis

> ... native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are
>   not affected.

Note though that if you're developing an enterprise app which is not available to the public, then it may not be allowed, see here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial

> However, not all commercial uses are allowed. For example, if your
>   site meets any of the following criteria you must purchase the
>   appropriate Google Maps API for Business license:
>
> - Your site is only accessible within your company or on your intranet.

Comment: It is alright to use Google Maps SDK for Enterprise App.

yes base on the Google Maps API Terms of Service

9.1.1 General Rules -> (b) Public Access -> (ii) :
"Your Maps API implementation must not operate only on an internal network (except during the development and testing phase)"

However, as indicated in 9.1.2 Exceptions -> (b) Mobile Applications -> (ii) :

**"The rule in Section 9.1.1(b) (Public Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is an Android application that uses the Google Maps Android API."**

it is also applicable to iOS since it falls in Mobile App category

Comment: @krischu I suspect this exception only applies to Android, not iOS?

Comment: @Saxon Druce native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected.

Comment: Google Maps API + Google Places API + Google Maps API Web Services Usage Limits: http://pastebin.com/G94zXX5h

Comment: Is this still the case for mobile API? I believe you have to pay for each map load now.